# how to generate HTTPS related keys on Linux?

Tags: linux, encryption, https

For the https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid project we use the [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib) C++ HTTP server library configured with `CPPHTTPLIB_OPENSSL_SUPPORT` ; see its [simplesrv.cc](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/blob/master/example/simplesvr.cc) example.

For testing purposes we need to make it serve https://localhost:8089/

Two files (a certificate file, and a private key file) are required by its [`class SSLServer`](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/blob/master/httplib.h#L843)

How to generate them quickly on Linux/Debian?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/2072269 (since you'll only ever be able to make self-signed certs for localhost).

Comment: Thanks. Should I close my question?